# Keyboard shortcut for SQL 2008 Management Studio?

Tags: sql, keyboard-shortcuts

im missing Backspace shortcut key from SQL MS 2005 for Up button in Object Explorer Details in 2008 version.

My Google can't find it :) so my question is:

Is there keyboard shortcut for Up button in Object Explorer Details in SQL 2008 Management Studio?

Comment: I really don't understand the question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd>.